# What are the default values of all datatypes in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to know the default values of data-types in Dart.
Integer,Double,String,Dynamic and Boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for all types in Dart are `null` if nothing else is specified when declaring the variable. This includes `int`, `double`, `String` and so on.

> Uninitialized variables that have a nullable type have an initial value of `null`. (If you haven’t opted into null safety, then every variable has a nullable type.) Even variables with numeric types are initially null, because numbers—like everything else in Dart—are objects.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#default-value

Comment: @HimanshiJain If you are satisfied with my answer, please accept it. Or are there some details I am missing? If so, please tell me. :)

Comment: Yes I'm satisfied with your answer. Thank You!

Comment: Ok then, please mark the answer as accepted by setting a check mark on my answer.

Comment: Done! I'm new to Stack Overflow :') .